# Howto route VPN client traffic over a VPN tunnel with pfSense?

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn, pfsense

My pfSense box is running as an OpenVPN client and OpenVPN server.

The client tunnel connects our network (192.168.1.1/24) to a remote network (10.10.10.10/24) and works just fine.

The server allows remote users to connect to our network while on the go, and works just fine.

How can I route/forward traffic from remote users through the tunnel so they can also access 10.10.10.10/24 resources?

Comment: I've added `push "route 10.10.10.10 255.255.255.0"` to the OpenVPN server.  On a remote client I see the route comes through, but pings fail.

Answer (score 1):

Solved.  In my OpenVPN server.conf I needed to add the appropriate route and iroute ccd settings, (like the Thelonious example in the config).